# wait for webbrowser to load, then execute code

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that constantly claims a username on a website, so that when the social medium decides to release these usernames I will be the first in line to get it. Now, it does timeout which is a huge problem. So to fix it, I have tried to make it sign out of the account then sign back in.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If number_of_ticks > NumericUpDown1.Value Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/Account/Signout")
        While Not WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag")

        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", txtUsername.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd").SetAttribute("value", txtPassword.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SI").InvokeMember("Click")
        number_of_ticks = 0
    End If

    If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag" Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
        number_of_ticks += 1
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, after number_of_ticks reaches a certain number I want it to navigate to the log out page, and then once the web page is fully loaded, navigate to the other page where it puts the info in again to log in. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and all I get are errors when I try to run this. The code:

```
While Not WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
```

seems to not work at all, and especially the other codes such as the WaitForPageLoad.
I have looked for solutions and haven't found ANYTHING.

Comment: Please don't do that.

Comment: Don't do what?... If you're implying i'm breaking a rule on Xbox.com, you're wrong. They do not care about it, that is why they still release usernames, and if they didn't want you to do it there would be captcha forms. This already happens and they are fully aware of it, I just want to learn how to do it so I can get one.

Comment: Don't pound on live.xbox.com. It's not polite. Ah, if something can be done, doesn't neccessery mean it should.

Comment: Don't be ignorant. It isn't breaking their code of conduct. I don't want to sound rude, but If you aren't willing to help me out, then don't reply. Simple as that.

Comment: My sincere apologizes, and good luck in your quest.

Comment: @Achilles: Have you _asked_ xbox.com if they accept people wasting time by claiming a user name in a loop? Don't assume they're ok with that - ask them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders lol that's not my biggest concern right now, if they don't want it happening then they can put captcha's on their username change.